# How to avoid CSRF attack in Codeigniter Ajax call?

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, csrf

I try to implement CSRF Attack in My webapplication,its implemented using codeigniter framework, this framework already have a options for protect CSRF attack. My issue issue i dont have a idea how to avoid CSRF attack in Ajax Call. Anyone have a idea please help me.

Thanks

Comment: you question is a bit confusing - if you activate csrf in codeigniter, it will be availabe for any post request. it really doesn't matter if it happens via ajax submission or the traditional form submission.

Comment: it's CSRF Token not attach. Please properly explain your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following in your code, though my process may not be correct.

In the config.php set `$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;`

In every POST form if not using form helper, then before the submit button use the following hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name();?>" value="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash();?>">
```

Where Ajax is involved use code like -

```
..........
"ajax":{
    url:"<?=site_url();?>folder/controllername/methodname",
    type:"POST",
    "dataType" : "json",
    "data":{
    '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>' : '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>'
           },
       },
...............
```